# Unable to paste all text in a cell of LibreOffice Calc after copying from Excell

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I am struggling when copying a column containing long texts from Excel to Calc (LibreOffice), my texts are stripped and contain only the 256 first characteres.

It seems that is related to some limitations, but I don't know how to fix it.
Also when I copy cells one by one, it seems to work, but otherwise not.

- OS: Windows 10 (x64)
- Excel: Excel 2016
- LibreOffice Calc: Version: 5.3.7.2

Thanks,

Comment: By "when I take each cell apart it seems to work", do you mean that it works when you try to copy one cell at a time?

Comment: Yes this is what i mean

Comment: And if you try 2 cells?

Comment: To be more clear about it, it works only when I select all the content of the cell, not when I select the cell and press Ctrl+C, so i cannot try it with 2 cells. Thanks

Comment: I think that is better for me to edit the post with this information

Comment: As a test, what if you paste the column into Notepad++?

Comment: It works fine with Notepad++.

Comment: Try then pasting from Np++ to Calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to copy text (not formulae, formatting etc.) then here's one option:

- Copy the cells in Excel
- Switch to Calc
- Choose **Paste Special...** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) instead of Paste
- Select **DIF** from the list.

  [image: Paste Special]
- Click **OK**

When I tested it I was able to copy multiple cells at once and the text was not being truncated at 256 characters.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try, what means DIF ?

Comment: Data Interchange Format, it's a pretty old standard that was meant to enable importing/exporting data between different spreadsheet programs.